# Writing only the end of the line in java

Tags: java, string, file

Let's say I have a file that contains these information

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
```

now how can I ask the program to write ONLY 4 (which is the end of the first line) to a different file. But here's the trick, NOT depending on the user's input.

so after the program ends, the other file would contain

```
4
```

I tried trimming the Line (String=String1.trim()) and using the function endsWith() but I need to put a String inside these parentheses.

I started java 3 weeks ago, so please bear with me, thanks.

Comment: Post what code you have.

Comment: read first line, `split` it on comma (this will create array of String tokens), get last token (you can use array lenght-1), write this to new file (don't forget to close your file stream).

Comment: It is hard to tell, what is being asked here. At least provide expected output for a given example. The example provided suggests that the output will be the last field of the first line in the input file, given that the fields are delimited with comma in each line

Comment: Split the strings in the file into an list/array, get the last character in the string by getting its length then getting the length-1 character, write it to the the other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the split() function to split a line on a separator into a String array. So:

```
String x = "1,2,3,4";
String[] split = x.split(",");
```

now the split array contains the individual items, and you can get the last one like this:

```
String last = split[split.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()`

```
String line = in.nextLine();             // read a line

String[] tokens = line.split("[\\s,]+"); // splits the line into an array

out.write(tokens[tokens.length - 1]);    // print the last index of the array.
```

Answer (score 0):

- Read the file, line by line
- for each line, split the string ([String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)) with space and then access the last element in the array returned by split()
- Write the element to the new File (see [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) and [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)).

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadStringFromFileLineByLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("test.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                             if(line.Trim().endsWith( "4" )){
                stringBuffer.append(line);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
                              }
            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of file:");
            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
                   // write the buffer content to new file.
                   File file = new File("newfile.txt");
                   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                   writer.write(stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. The easy way: use [myString.subString(myString.length()-1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)

   The complex/professional way (overkill for your case but just for reference): Use a [regex pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) like this.

```
final String input = "1, 2, 3, 4";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.)\\s*$");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Where the pattern used means:

- `(.)` - ()capture .any single char
- `\\s*` - followed by 0 or more white-space chars
- `$` - followed by the end of line